# JQuery Datatable not loading Json data from MVC Controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have an **Asp.Net MVC 5** web application. I am using **JQuery Datatables v1.10.16** to display tabular data within one of the razor views. The data being returned to the datatable is via an **ajax call** and returning **Json**.

This is my razor view

```
<table id="data_table" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Evaluation ID</td>
            <td>Applicant Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Evaluation ID</td>
            <td>Applicant Name</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#data_table').DataTable({
            "ajax": '/EvalDashboard/GetEvaluationData',
            "dataSrc": 'evaluations',
            "columns": [
            { data: 'evaluationID' },
            { data: 'applicantName' }
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

This is my method which is called inside the controller EvalDashboard

```
    public JsonResult GetEvaluationData()
    {

        var evaluations = _evalService.GetAllCecEvaluations(null, null)
            .Take(20).Select(x => new
            {
                evaluationID = x.EvaluationID,
                applicantName = x.tblcourseapplicant.FullName
            }).ToList();

        return Json(evaluations, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When I run the app, I can see that the method `GetEvaluationData()` is being called, however, no data is returned to the datatable in the view, I only get a message saying Loading...

I'm not sure if the problem is because I'm returning an annonymous type inside my method.

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had not included the keyword `data` inside the Json return statement like so:

```
return Json(new { data = evaluations }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This fixed the problem I was having.